# How to validate timestamp in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In my chess app I use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to record the time of a move, e.g.:

```
{
  from: 'e2',
  to: 'e4',
  playedAt: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}
```

How could I validate that `playedAt` is `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and not an arbitrary timestamp like 1408663907743?

I expected Firebase Security Rules to have a method like `isTimestamp()` that would work similarly to `isNumber()` and `isString()`, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Does this answer from Jenny help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25433017/209103

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use security rules to prevent a user from faking Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433016/how-do-you-use-security-rules-to-prevent-a-user-from-faking-firebase-servervalue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timestamps in Firebase, like the one that corresponds to the server side macro `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` are stored like any other number. No additional type information is stored that makes them special. So, `isTimestamp()` would be equivalent to `isNumber()`.

If you'd like to further validate that the timestamp matches the current server time, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25433017/209103).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `now` special keyword it is equal to epoch time (millisecond)

```
"playedAt": {
   ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() === now"
}
```

If you are generating time from another source, you can convert it to millisecond and use something like this (10 - 20 second clock drift)

```
"playedAt": {
   ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() - 10000 < now && newData.val() + 10000 > now"
}
```